# pandas: how to add a character to all integer columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe c like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('x', index=range(3), columns=list('ab0123'))

    a   b   0   1   2   3
0   x   x   x   x   x   x
1   x   x   x   x   x   x
2   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

And I want to convert the columns 0,1,2,3 to a0, a1, a2, a3 so that it looks like the following:

```
        a   b   a0  a1  a2  a3
    0   x   x   x   x   x   x
    1   x   x   x   x   x   x
    2   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

I have tried the following code, but it did not change the column.

```
c.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns = 't' + c.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns.astype(str)
```

Comment: `df.columns = [f'a{col}' if col.isdigit() else col for col in df]` may work fine

Comment: You shouldn't want to use `select_dtypes` since this checks the type of the actual columns, rather than looking at the column header itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string methods defined on the header:

```
cols = df.columns
np.where(cols.str.isdigit(), 'a' + cols, cols) 
# array(['a', 'b', 'a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'], dtype=object)

df.columns = np.where(cols.str.isdigit(), 'a' + cols, cols) 
df
   a  b a0 a1 a2 a3
0  x  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

---

Or @jpp's list comprehension works nice too.

```
df.columns = [f'a{col}' if col.isdigit() else col for col in df]
# df.columns = ['a' + col if c.isdigit() else col for col in df]

df
   a  b a0 a1 a2 a3
0  x  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x  x
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a stretch, but it solves the problem. Use the filter method to separate digits header columns from numeric header columns, add prefix ('a') to digits headers column and concat dataframe back. As noted, it is a stretch.

```
pd.concat([df.filter(regex='[a-z]'),
           df.filter(regex='\d').add_prefix('a')],
           axis=1)

    a   b   a0  a1  a2  a3
0   x   x   x   x   x   x
1   x   x   x   x   x   x
2   x   x   x   x   x   x
```